# How to copy a string to clipboard from vim in a panel to another panel in tmux?

Tags: vim, tmux

Using tmux, I opened two panels.
On the left panel, I opened a file using vim and input some characters.

I want to copy those characters to the right side panel of tmux. How to do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to copy/paste in tmux, you just do it as usual, it doesn't matter left side is vim or other process.

On the left side, you enter **tmux's** copy-mode (with your shortcut), select lines,  do copy (copy to **tmux's** buffer), switch to right side, paste (with your shortcut). Done.